# Отправка сообщений в чат стрима с помощью Youtube API

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

Возникла проблема с API Youtube ,ищу уже второй день - ничего не могу найти.

**Задача : С помощью API Youtube отправлять сообщения в чат прямой трансляции.**

> Вот ссылки на похожие вопросы (к сожалению на них нет ответа :( ) :
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082103/send-message-in-channel-chat-in-live-streaming-using-youtube-api
>
> [Стрим Бот для чата youtube](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661471/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request = youtube.liveChatMessages().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "liveChatId": "YOUR_LIVE_CHAT_ID",
            "type": "textMessageEvent",
            "textMessageDetails": {
              "messageText": "текст сообщения"
            }
          }
        }
    )
```